Saving a file and other data to a database using Angular and Spring Boot
I'd like to save a file and other data to the database. After reading a lot I gather that this is very possible using both FormGroup and FormData. Could someone please look at my code and advise where I'm going wrong.
my service
imageUploadForm = new FormGroup({description: new FormControl(null)});
formObj = this.imageUploadForm.value;
data = JSON.stringify(this.formObj);

public createImageFormData(productImage: ProductImage, imageFile: File): FormData {
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('data', this.data);
formData.append('name', imageFile.name); 
formData.append('imageFile', imageFile);

new Response(formData).text().then(console.log) // only name of the image and the image are being appended
return formData;
}

The template
<form #newImageForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddNewImage(newImageForm)">
      <div>
          <label>Description</label>
          <input
            name="description"
            id="description"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter description here"
            
          />
      </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <div class="custom-file">
          <input
          multiple
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            name="location"
            (change)="onImageUrlChange($event)"
            class="custom-file-input"
          />
          <label class="custom-file-label"
            ><span [hidden]="!fileName">{{ fileName }}</span>
          </label>

          <img *ngFor='let url of images'  [src]="url" height="150" width="200px" style="margin: 3px;"> <br/>
        </div>
      </div>
      
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>


For uploading it's easier to just add an id to the form... ex:  <form id="newImageForm" #newImageForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddNewImage()"> Then do: let form = document.getElementById('newImageForm')! as HTMLFormElement;
let formData = new FormData(form);   Just put that in your upload service method.
You should add your code for onAddNewImage, and onImageUrlChange.  (add the full controller code, too)

@browsermator do you have a clear example of how to do this.

I can post what I have for front-end.  (I do this in edit and allow uploading one image at a time... there are some other reasons for that, but you can use multiple if you like)  I don't preview before upload, results returned include an array of imageIDs so they show only if upload was successful... My backend is in .NET so not sure I can help with Spring backend stuff.

Here's what I use.  Hopefully it helps a little.
View (form in editinventoryitem.component.html)  I do this in Edit view so that I ensure this record has already been created.  Otherwise you'd need to create a blank record on the backend first in case the user browses for/adds image files before filling out the other fields.  You don't necessarily need to respond to onchange input files immediately, though.  So you can leave out the preview and just upload/submit the form, and/or handle image previews client-side only if wanted.  I update previews once file has been successfully uploaded here.  There are reasons I do it this way that probably don't apply to you.  This code only allows JPGs and one image upload at a time:
 <form id="editInventoryItemForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #editInventoryItemForm="ngForm"> 
     <div *ngIf="editInventoryItemDetails?.images">
        <div *ngIf="editInventoryItemDetails?.images!.length>0">
          <span *ngFor="let thisImage of editInventoryItemDetails?.images; let i=index">
            <span class="container"><a href="{{baseURL}}/WebApi/ServeJpg?id={{thisImage.id}}"><img class="inventory-item-image" src="{{baseURL}}/WebApi/ServeJpg?id={{thisImage.id}}" /></a><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm image-overlay" (click)="removeImage(i)">X</button></span>
          </span>
          <br /><br /><label for="ImageFile" class="control-label" id="uploadText">
  &nbsp;Upload Image File(.jpg only):

  <input name="ImageFile" (change)="uploadImage()" id="ImageFile" type="file" class="form-control" accept=".jpg, .jpeg" />
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="editInventoryItemDetails?.images">
        <div *ngIf="editInventoryItemDetails?.images!.length==0">
          <label for="ImageFile" class="control-label" id="uploadText">
            &nbsp;Upload Image File (.jpg only):

            <input name="ImageFile" (change)="uploadImage()"  id="ImageFile" type="file" class="form-control" accept=".jpg, .jpeg" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>

Controller method (in editinventoryitem.component.ts) :
  onSubmit() {
   
    let submitButton = document.getElementById("submit_button") as HTMLButtonElement;
    submitButton.innerHTML = "Editing...";
    submitButton.disabled = true;

    this.editInventoryItemService.postEdit(this.editInventoryItemDetails!, this.removePDF).subscribe(editInventoryResults => {
      this.router.navigate(['/inventoryitemdetails/' + editInventoryResults.inventoryItem.id], { queryParams: this.viewState });
    });
  }


uploadImage() {
    
    let fileInput = document.getElementById("ImageFile") as HTMLInputElement;
    let uploadText = document.getElementById("uploadText") as HTMLLabelElement;
   
    if (fileInput.files) {
      //check for .jpg
      let fileString = fileInput.files[0].name;
      let fileBits = fileString.split('.') as String[];
      let numBits = fileBits.length;
      let extension = fileBits[numBits - 1];
    
      if (extension == "jpg" || extension == "JPG" || extension == "jpeg" || extension == "JPEG") {
       this.editInventoryItemService.uploadImage().subscribe(itemResults => {
       this.editInventoryItemDetails = itemResults;
       fileInput.value = "";
   
        });
      }
      else {
        alert('This file is not a JPEG.  Check to be sure the extension is .jpg or .jpeg');
        fileInput.value = "";
       
      }
    }
}
 
removeImage(index: number) {
   
    if (this.editInventoryItemDetails?.images[index]) {
      this.editInventoryItemDetails!.images[index]!.removed = 1;
      this.editInventoryItemService.removeInventoryItemImage(this.editInventoryItemDetails!.images[index]!)
        .subscribe(results => {
          if (results) { this.editInventoryItemDetails!.images.splice(index, 1); }
        });
    }
  }

Service method (in editinventoryservice.service.ts):
 postEdit(itemToEdit: EditInventoryItem, removePDF: string): Observable<EditInventoryItem>  {
   let form = document.getElementById('editInventoryItemForm')! as HTMLFormElement;
   let formData = new FormData(form);
   return this.http.post<EditInventoryItem>(this.editInventoryItemURL, formData)
     .pipe(
       tap(_ => this.serviceservice.log('edit inventory item')),
       catchError(this.serviceservice.handleError<EditInventoryItem>('Edit Inventory Item'))
     );
 }

  uploadImage(): Observable<EditInventoryItem> {

    let form = document.getElementById('editInventoryItemForm')! as HTMLFormElement;
    let formData = new FormData(form);

    return this.http.post<EditInventoryItem>(this.addInventoryItemImageURL, formData)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.serviceservice.log('upload image')),
        catchError(this.serviceservice.handleError<EditInventoryItem>('upload image'))
      );
  }

  removeInventoryItemImage(inventoryItemImageToRemove: InventoryItemImage): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.deleteInventoryItemImageURL, inventoryItemImageToRemove)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.serviceservice.log('remove inventory item image')),
        catchError(this.serviceservice.handleError<EditInventoryItem>('remove inventory item image'))
      );
  }


Thanks I solved this issue. I meant saving a file alongside other data like username, email etc. I have managed to save multiple files as follows.


    postProductData(productImages: ProductImage, files: File[]): 
      FormData {
    
      let formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('userName', productImages.userName!);
      formData.append('email', productImages.email!);
      for (const file of files) {
      formData.append("files", file, file.name);
      }
      return formData;
    }

and the entity

    

>     @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
      private String name;
      @Column(name = "imageurl", nullable = false)
      URL  location;
      @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
      private String userName;
      @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
      private String email;

